# XML Injector to test API load

Tags: xml, testing

I developed an API for a Web Service which takes in Input XML Files and answers using XML Files too.

Do you know a Tool / Framework I could use on Linux to test my API like: 10 requests / seconds; 20 requests / Seconds and so on...

I didn't find any tool to help me do this. Except if i develop my own framework..

Thank you for your help !

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ab2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) (apache bench) or [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/). They both allow you to adjust total number of requests and the level on concurrency.

Comment: Well siege seems quite powerful ! Is it possible to POST some xml file using this tool ?

Comment: Yes, [check the examples](http://linux.die.net/man/1/siege) it could go something like: `host/file POST < input.txt`